# How to Uninstall Eclipse IDE and the packages that were installed, during installation process in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, eclipse, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

I had installed Eclipse IDE for Java, I found it difficult to use and I switched to IntelliJ Idea.
I ran this command

```
cd .local/share/applications/ 
rm *eclipse*.desktop epp*.desktop
```

It removed the Eclipse Ide,now are the packages also removed that were installed during installation process. If No, then how should I remove the packages ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In the case you are using the packge by unzip and run the the sh file to start the eclipse. we can find the folder that stores the eclipse packe and delete it.

Find the folder: sudo find f . -name {1 file name you know}
After that you can remove all folder - that include this file. If you have UI you can access directly to folder to check it before remove all of them